# Convert custom date/time field to date only

Tags: office-scripts

I have a csv file that brings in all dates as date/time in a "custom" format. It displays as 12/31/2021  12:00:00 AM but when I use

Part1NoBlanks.getRange("C2:C6000").setNumberFormatLocal("m/d/yyyy");

it still retains the time for any cell that has a time other than 12:00:00 AM. For example:

3/26/2020  12:00:00 AM displays as 3/26/2020
6/5/2023  11:00:00 PM  still displays as 6/5/2023  11:00:00 PM

What am I missing in my script to account / address this? Thank you in advance for your help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a limitation of Excel itself rather than an Office Script issue. Manually updating the format of "text date" usually causes the same problem too. Regardless, it's easy to fix with code.

btw, Using `getIntersection()` to narrow the data range will improve code performance.

```js
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    // Update your Worksheet object 
    let Part1NoBlanks = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
    let useRange = Part1NoBlanks.getUsedRange();
    let dataRange = Part1NoBlanks.getRange("C2:C6000").getIntersection(useRange);
    let dataValues = dataRange.getValues();
    dataRange.clear(ExcelScript.ClearApplyTo.contents);
    dataRange.setNumberFormatLocal("m/d/yyyy");
    dataRange.setValues(dataValues);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. The code you provided did not get rid of displaying the time but I also realized I did not mention that it "only" displays in the formula window and not on the worksheet view.

So it works for sorting. Your code provides the same result as the line of code I provided but I appreciate the heads up onb the "get Intersection" and will implement that in my process so I appreciate you!!!